# How to Achieve HOME SCREEN LAUNCHER in my Android Application?

Tags: android

i have develop my application in android.
Now i want to  make Home Screen Launcher. and i want to call that Home-Screen launcher from my activity.
So,,how to achieve this,please give me suggestions to make Home-Screen launcher and how to call it from my application??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Home Screen Launcher, I think you mean Home Screen Activity and a demo Home Screen Activity is in the samples directory of the SDK. Remember that a replacement for the default Home Screen can only be setup/activated by the user as a security measure. Otherwise you can start it through an Intent, but it won't last unless the user sets it as the default.

See [Home Screen Activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)