# create application like android home screen

Tags: android

I want to make an application which will look like android home screen. where I want to place some icons. it will have 10 pages. I want to do scroll between these pages.
How to achieve this? Plz help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to archive the home-screen like switching but for the icons, you can use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html). To switch between the pages, a [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) could be used. Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535011/how-to-achieve-home-screen-launcher-in-my-android-application), which might be what you're searching for.

But there might be bettwer ways of doing this...